# CISCO SNMP fcIfFLoginTable oid result

Tags: cisco, snmp, fibre-channel

Looking at an SNMP walk over 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.289.1.1.5.1.3 ([enterprise.cisco.ciscoMgmt.ciscoFcFeMIB.ciscoFcFeObjects.cffFcFeConfig.fcIfFLoginTable.fcIfFLoginEntry.fcIfNxPortNodeName](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.289.1.1.5.1.3&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true)) on a CISCO FC switch, I'm seeing results of the form:

```
'1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.289.1.1.5.1.3.x.[23].y' => '0xWWN',
```

Through some walking, I've determined that `x` is the switch port identifier used, for example, in [1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.289.1.1.2.1.1](http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?objectInput=1.3.6.1.4.1.9.9.289.1.1.2.1.1&translate=Translate&submitValue=SUBMIT&submitClicked=true).  **My question is: what are the [23] and `y`?**

A full walk shows that `y` is only used in the fcIfFLoginTable, but I'd still like to know its significance, as it appears unique.

Comment: Did you check the MIB ?

Comment: yes.  what i know comes from a mixture of cisco's lookup service, snmp walking, and reading through their mibs.  everything after ..5.1.3 is not documented.